# How to get the number from the script's result by shell command?

Tags: shell

I run a command and get below result:

```
numid=181,iface=MIXER,name='pcm1_in Gain 0 Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=-1440,max=360,step=0
  : values=-360,-360
  | dBscale-min=-144.00dB,step=0.10dB,mute=0
```

I need to get the value -360, and this value can vary from -1440 to 360. How to use some shell commands and regular expression to do it? Thanks!

Comment: which -360 you need of -360,-360? first or second? Is the output a single line or multiple line?

Comment: Either is OK. They are always equal. The output has 4 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe your command to sed.

For one line output:

```
yourcommand | sed -n 's/.*: values=\(-*[^,]*\),.*/\1/p'
```

For multiline output:

```
yourcommand | sed -n ':a;$!N;s/\n/ /;ta;s/.*: values=\(-*[^,]*\),.*/\1/p'
```

The string between `: values=` and `,` is captured and output using backreference